# Returning the default value for the key that cannot be found in the javascript object

Tags: javascript

When a key that is not in the object is called, it returns undefined. I want to return a string that I specify instead of undefined. for example

```js
let obj = {
  key1: 'key1'
}
let res = obj.key2;

console.log(res);
```

I want `console.log (res)` to return **"key not found"**, not `undefined`.

Is this possible?

Comment: This makes sense if the string you're going to return is a default value for `key2` but I'm not sure it makes sense if it simply represents an alternative indicator for undefined. Why do you want to return "key not found"?

Comment: In the frontend part, I keep the error codes that will come from the api in the object.
let errors = {101: 'User Not Found, 102:' User Banned '}
However, when I get an error code other than api, I want to show the 'Something went wrong' error.
let res = errors ['103'];
I want a 'Something Occurred' statement in res.

Comment: One common way to deal with this is for your back-end to throw a custom exception that would be caught higher in your code and returned to the client as an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error with some text and the text could be what you included in the exception, for example: `throw new InternalError('Not found: key2')` though typically you would not actually surface that internal error context to the client (you would error log it and return some generic message to the user, perhaps including an identifier relating to the error log that you made).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could take  the [Nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), which repects other [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values than `undefined` or `null`.

```js
let obj = { key1: 'key1' },
    res = obj.key2 ?? 'key2 not found';

console.log(res);
```

If `undefined`/`null` are real values, the key should be checked in advance.

```js
let obj = { key1: null },
    res = 'key1' in obj ? obj.key1 : 'key2 not found';

console.log(res);
```

Comment: yes I thought about it, but I use the object almost everywhere in the system. So I want to define this once in a root domain. Can't I edit an object class?

Comment: you could use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and shape the access.

Answer (score 2):

according to the [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) document you could do that like this:

```js
const obj = {
  key1: "key1",
};

const handler = {
  get(target, prop) {
    return target[prop] ? target[prop] : "specific value";
  },
};

const proxy = new Proxy(obj, handler);

console.log(proxy.key1) //key1
console.log(proxy.key2) //"specific value"
```